# radiobutton text not displaying underscore (_) wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
  var item = new RadioButton { Content = "some_name"};
      item.Checked += radioButtonClick;
      item.Unchecked += radioButtonUnClick;
```

actual display is somename. Underscore is missing. To fix this used the following style on the radio button, but it has side effects. Radiobutton icon is not visible.

```
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type RadioButton}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="False"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are actually asking a different question to the title, perhaps a rename would be a good idea?:)

Comment: Add Radio button code where you are using this style and as @Chris suggested renaming title would be good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display `underscore` in `radiobutton` please use below code.

```
<RadioButton ...... >
    <TextBlock Text="SELECT_ME" />
</RadioButton>
```

For code behind

```
var item = new RadioButton { Content = new TextBlock { Text = "SELECT_ME" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double underscores, since a single underscore followed by a letter is interpreted as the definition of an access key. Access keys appear underlined when you press the Alt key.

If you want "some_name" to appear on your label/checkbox/button/.. you need to specify the content as "some__name".

You can read more about access keys in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-control-that-has-an-access-key-and-text-wrapping